# Upgrade from Windows 10 Home to Pro fails with error code 0xc004f050

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-pro

I have a PC running Windows 10 Home (valid license and activated). Now I bought a Windows 10 Pro Upgrade license (OEM) to upgrade that PC to Windows 10 Professional.
If I enter the license key in the system panel to upgrade, this fails with this error code:

```
0xc004f050
```

I bought the license for a reasonable price from a trustworthy vendor, so I believe that the license key is valid.
How can I activate/upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just **restart** your PC after trying to enter your upgrade key. By this, Windows would magically update some files. After the restart, you will have an unactivated Windows Pro, just **enter your license key again** to activate your Pro version!